# Hamburger sidebar hiding with transition in React.js and sass/css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm missing something here...I thought that is easy but for some reason I cannot solve this.

I'm trying to open and close sidebar from a right side of the page. Of course, at the beginning you cannot see it, then on click (to hamburger) it appears, then again on click (on hamburger) it should dissapear. All with smooth transition. I can do the first one (it shows nicely), the second one - it dissapears but without the transition, I cannot solve that. I'm toggling two classes with onClick event:

```
<div className="hamburgerContainer">
     <button onClick={() => this.handleHam()} className={hamClass}  type="button">
           <span className="hamburger-box hamburgerContainers">
            <span className="hamburger-inner"></span>
           </span>
     </button>
</div>
```

Toggling hamburgerClass, hamClass is not important here:

```
handleHam() {
    const { hamClass, hamburgerClass } = this.state;
    hamClass === 'hamburger hamburger--spin' && hamburgerClass === 'hamburgerMenuClose' ? 
    this.setState({ hamClass: 'hamburger hamburger--spin is-active', hamburgerClass: "hamburgerMenu" }):
    this.setState({ hamClass: 'hamburger hamburger--spin', hamburgerClass: 'hamburgerMenuClose' })
}
```

My sass file:

```
@media (max-width: 750px){
    .hamburgerMenu {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        right: -300px; 
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        transform: translate(-100%, 0); 
        transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    }
    .hamburgerMenuClose {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        right: 0px;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        transform: translate(0, 0); 
        transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
    }


}
```